# Do all plants have meristems?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, tissue

Are there any plants that lack a meristem (at any phase in their lifecycle)?

Searching for it on the web, the materials I find seem to assume no, but none say it explicitly.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology! It might be handy to look at the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and check out other materials provided about the community. With regard to your question: can you please directly show the information that you found so that we can evaluate it? Where have you looked? What do you mean by "meristem"? Note that there are [unicellular plants](https://lambdageeks.com/unicellular-plants-examples/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider plants to be photosynthetic eukaryotes, some of them have shapes that wouldn't require a meristem in the same sense as the plants we commonly see. i.e

[Volvox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvox) is spherical. Cells in all organized structure communicate with each other by chemical signals that diffuse through neighbour cells and give knowledge of orientation and distance from neighbours.

All plants with organized structures that grow against gravity would probably have reduced fitness if they lacked meristems.

It's a good idea to read about the [evolution of meristems](https://www.google.com/search?q=evolution%20of%20meristems&oq=evolution%20of%20meristems&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.3648j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to find out what recent research has found.

Meristems are often the apical cells, so free plants in the water and at smaller sizes, plants don't have a right way up.

Comment: Thanks; I wonder whether there are larger photosynthetic eukaryotes than volvox w/o meristems. Maybe I should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Also maybe you should add a note about unicellular plants in your answer (see the first (and as of writing only) comment on the question).